# replicating a feature in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have been pouring over Zend_View and the various classes and interfaces that make up the view. One thing I am attempting to replicate in a project that does not use zend in any way shape or form is the:

```
$this->view->variable = 'Hello world';
```

that you can set in a controller and then do:

```
echo $this->view->variable;
```

My ultimate goal is to do something like:

```
$this->variable = new SomeClass
```

and then else where, in a view specifically, do:

```
$this->variable->someMethod();
```

My question is:

- How would I replicate what zend does to do something simmilar with out using global variables?
- How is zend able to do something like $this->view with out ever instantiating or saying what view is?

this would help me understand how, variables are passed around or objects are passed from the logic to the view and how php allows for something like $this->view to work when in a view or not.

**note**: this is not a Zend specific question and "use zend" is not the answer. I am looking to replicate a specific feature. My project does not in any way use or affiliate with zend.

Comment: that has nothing to do with zend. that's just normal OOP. zend cannot do anything that PHP itself can't. zend's just a bunch of extra stuff on top of php, written in php (or at least as php modules) to make your life easier. But even if you don't have a zend "hammer", there's still the usual php rock to pound in that nail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple.  When you use `include`, `require`, `eval` et al., the loaded code is brought in to the current scope.  So if you have a template file

**template.php**

```
<span><?=$this->view->somevar?></span>
```

**Controller.php**

```
<?php
class Controller
{
    private $view;

    public function doSomething()
    {
        $this->view->somevar = 'Hello World';
        include 'template.php';
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
require 'Controller.php';
$oC = new Controller();
$oC->doSomething();
```

Blamo.., template.php is able to call `$this->view->somevar` as it is treated as part of Controller.php.  Running `php index.php` on the CLI produces

```
<span>Hello World</span>
```

To elaborate a tiny bit, if `$this->view` inside of Controller.php were a class you've defined rather than a simple instance of `stdClass` as in the above demonstration, and it had a function `someMethod`, you could call `$this->view->someMethod()` from template.php just the same.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why exactly you want to achieve this, but as a super simple setup (which is by no means suited to be the basis of an MVC framework) you can look at this:

```
<?php
class Controller
{
    private $view = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->view = new View();
        $this->view->someVar = "foobar";
    }

    public function render()
    {
        include "view.php";
    }
}

class View
{

}

$controller = new Controller();
$controller->render();
```

And then, in view.php, you can do:

```
<?php
echo $this->view->someVar;
```

Beware: This code only shows HOW it's possible to achieve such a construct, it does not anything useful at all ;).